# SOCK_STREAM issue with Raspberry Pi 4 as client in client/server test

Tags: python, server, sockets

I am trying a simple client/server Python socket program between my MacBook Pro and Raspberry Pi 4. This code is from Computer Networking: A Top Down Approach [Kurose, Ross].

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import *

server_name = '192.168.0.17'
server_port = 12345

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((server_name, server_port))

message = input('string to capitalise: ')

client_socket.send(message.encode())

modified_message = client_socket.recv(1024)

print('from server:', modified_message.decode())

client_socket.close()
```

Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import *

server_port = 12345
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)         
server_socket.bind(('', server_port))               
server_socket.listen(1)                             

print('the server is ready to receive')

while True :
    connection_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()     
    message = connection_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    modified_message = message.upper()
    connection_socket.send(modified_message.encode())
    connection_socket.close()
```

I have no issue when the the Pi is the server and Mac is the client, however vice versa (Pi = client, Mac = server) the client program will run but not display the prompt ('string to capialise:') or progress the program further.

I tried changing the socket type to UDP (SOCK_DGRAM) and this had no issues, so I am led to believe this might be a TCP matter. Has anyone else had this issue?